# onPress in TouchableOpacity doesn't trigger

Tags: react-native

I need your help! My goal is to change the style of my button after I clicked it! I heard about [direct manipulation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation.html) and I decided to give it a try. Now I don't know why but the onPress inside my TouchableOpacity doesn't work. Here is the code:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.changeStyle}>
   <TouchableHighlight style={styles.answer} ref="answer1">
      <Text ...> Some Text </Text>
   </TouchableHighlight>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

And here is my changeStyle function:

```
changeStyle() {
   this.refs['answer1'].setNativeProps({
      style: { backgroundColor: "#13a88a"}
   });
}
```

Now i don't know why but the 'onPress' is never triggered.
Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Add an `onPress` to the `TouchableHighlight` and output something to test whether that takes the event. I suspect it will do.

Comment: @G0dsquad i already did that, the onPress inside TouchableHighlight works. The problem is i can't call the function changeStyle inside it because it's that TouchableHighlight which i want to change the style. And setNativeProps only works with the child of the container (here TouchableOpacity is the container and TouchableHighlight is the child).

Comment: can you please try by adding `()` to `this.changeStyle`

Comment: @JigarShah thank you, i changed that but nothing happened, `onPress` is still not triggered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to execute the function by using 'this.changeStyle`, write your onPress like so:

`<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.changeStyle}/>`

If you're going to pass a function within the onPress prop that executes `this.changeStyle` write your onPress like so:

`<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.changeStyle()}/>`

P.S: Why do you have `<TouchableHighlight/>` inside a `<TouchableOpacity/>`? Just use one and add the onPress prop on it.

Comment: Thank you! Why i'm using `TouchableHighlight` inside `TouchableOpacity` is because in the documentation i saw that `setNativeProps` is used to update the child's props. And I want to change the style of the button, in this case the `TouchableHighlight` and the `Text` inside it

Comment: Then I see no use for the TouchableOpacity. You can add onPress to TouchableHighlight and it'll work too. If it solved your issue, please do mark it as solved though.

Answer (score 3):

You need to import `TouchableOpacity` from `react-native` instead of importing it from `react-native-gesture-handler`. The version in `react-native-gesture-handler` is 100% broken. The version in `react-native` works.